# when use python mako how to return other type data

Tags: python, mako

```
from mako.template import Template

t=Template("${x}").render(x=[1,2,3])
print(type(t))   # <class 'str'>
print(t)         # [1, 2, 3]

t=Template("${x}").render(x=5)
print(type(t))  #<class 'str'>
print(t)        # 5
```

Why return is not a list or int, what do I want to get

can i use ?,But I was disappointed

```
t=Template("${int(x)}").render(x=5)
print(type(t))   #<class 'str'>
print(t)         #5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type cast to the data type you want, using

`t = int(Template("${int(x)}").render(x=5))`

or

`t = [Template("${int(x)}").render(x=5)]`

Comment: <class 'list'>
['[1, 2, 3]']
<class 'int'>
5